# What is a MVC4 pluggable approach using Areas with external projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have decided to use asp.net-MVC4, Doing some POC and stuck with manging bigger solution then I have found solution posted by @nilesh http://nileshhirapra.blogspot.sg/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-pluggable-application.html.

It is working fine for MVC3, but when try to implement same in MVC4, my area solution views will throw error saying `no extension register for .cshtml.` using ASP .net mvc 4 empty solution?

Comment: Did you get this working on MVC4? I am hitting the same issue right now.

Comment: Nvm, I found it. The link you provided is for MVC3 and it worked out right with MVC4 as well.